# PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Tags: php, html, css, pdo

Please help not able to resolve, trying since three days but not able to know what the reason its throwing me such message. (below is my complete code).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Insert New Post</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="insert_post.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table align="center" border="10" width="600">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="5" bgcolor="yellow"><h1>Insert New Post Here</h1></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="right">Post Title:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="title" size="40"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">Post Author:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="author"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">Post image:</td>
        <td><input type="file" name="image_name"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">Post Content:</td>
        <td><textarea name="content" cols="50" rows="20"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td align="center" colspan="5"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Publish Now"></td>
    </tr>

</table>    

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Above Form is to insert and submit data in Database

```
// PHP 

  <?php 
include("includes/connect.php");

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $datenow = date('Y/m/d');
    $author = $_POST['author'];
    $content = $_POST['content'];
    $image_name = $_FILES['image_name']['name'];
    $image_type = $_FILES['image_name']['type'];
    $image_size = $_FILES['image_name']['size'];
    $image_tmp = $_FILES['image_name']['tmp_name'];

    if ($title =='' || $author =='' || $content =='') {
        echo "<script>alert('Any feild is empty')</script>";
        exit();
    }
    if ($image_type =='image/jpeg' || $image_type =='image/png' || $image_type =='image/gif') {

        if ($image_size<=5000000000) {
            move_uploaded_file($image_tmp, "images/$image_name");
        }
        else{
            echo "<script>alert('Image is larger, only 50kb size is allowed')        </script>";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "<script>alert('image type is invalid')</script>";
    }

    // insert query
              $sth = $con->prepare(" INSERT INTO posts (post_title, post_date,   post_author, post_image, post_content) VALUE (:title,:datenow,:author,:image_name,:content) ");

    $sth->bindParam(':post_title', $title);
    $sth->bindParam(':post_date', $datenow);
    $sth->bindParam(':post_author', $author);
    $sth->bindParam(':post_image', $image_name);
    $sth->bindParam(':post_content', $content);

       $sth->execute();

 echo "<h1>Form Submited Successfully</h1>";

}

?>

   // $sth->execute(); is throwing error massage as above
```

Comment: You are binding `:title,:datenow,:author..` Not `:post_title,:post_date..`

Answer (score 2):

You are binding wrong values.You haven't bind the post_* values. See below:

```
$sth = $con->prepare(" INSERT INTO posts (post_title, post_date, post_author, post_image, post_content) VALUES (:post_title,:post_date,:post_author,:post_image,:post_content) ");

$sth->bindParam(':post_title', $title);
$sth->bindParam(':post_date', $datenow);
$sth->bindParam(':post_author', $author);
$sth->bindParam(':post_image', $image_name);
$sth->bindParam(':post_content', $content);
```

Comment: Thanks.Im glad to help you.